# Where Does Jenkins Performance Trend Reports are Stored?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, performance-testing

Where does Jenkins **Performance Trend** Reports are stored? I have created another jenkins job, which needs to carry forward from the existing report from the current job.

[image]

Comment: Ideally the reports will be stored in the build history folder under job folder